# Are there any projects that started out as a Prolog prototype

Tags: prolog

PyPy's JIT started out as a Prolog prototype: http://morepypy.blogspot.com/2008/06/hi-all-some-news-from-jit-front.html.

Gambit Scheme and Erlang also started out implemented in Prolog.

Are there any other notable (or not so notable) projects that started out in Prolog and then reimplemented in a more mainstream language ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Mercury](http://www.mercury.csse.unimelb.edu.au/) was bootstrapped in Prolog, just like Erlang.